# package com.codename1.charts does not exist

Tags: java, codenameone

I want to test the GeoVizDemo [https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Demos/GeoVizDemo] app in this blog post https://www.codenameone.com/blog/geo-visualization-library.html but when I have opened up the project in Netbeans the files in /src DensityChart.java, GeoVizDemo.java and PopulationData.java all have errors such as

package com.codename1.io does not exist or
package com.codename1.charts does not exist

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is missing some jar files. To fix this, follow these steps:

- Create a new CN1 Project. Set your package name to `com.codename1.demos.geoviz` and Main Class to `GeoVizDemo`. Choose Flat Blue theme and Hello world(visual) template.
- Download [CN1GeoViz.cn1lib](https://github.com/shannah/CN1GeoViz/releases/download/1.0/CN1GeoViz.cn1lib) and copy it to your lib folder.
- Download [DensityChart.java](http://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Demos/GeoVizDemo/src/com/codename1/demos/geoviz/DensityChart.java), [GeoVizDemo.java](http://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Demos/GeoVizDemo/src/com/codename1/demos/geoviz/GeoVizDemo.java) and [PopulationData.java](http://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Demos/GeoVizDemo/src/com/codename1/demos/geoviz/PopulationData.java), copy them to `src/com/codename1/demos/geoviz` folder (Replace any file in there).
- Download [pop_density.csv](http://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Demos/GeoVizDemo/src/pop_density.csv) and [us-states.json](http://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Demos/GeoVizDemo/src/us-states.json), copy them to the project main folder.
- Open your project properties in Netbeans or Eclipse and Update project Library.
- Right click on your project and Choose Codenameone -> Refresh Libs.
- Do a clean build and fix any error showing and that's it.